# Limit a @SendToUser broadcast on a specific browser tab

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I am using STOMP `websocket` on Springboot and want to limit a broadcast to a particular page. Here is my process:

1. `User` fills up a message to a HTML input.
2. Browser will send the message through STOMP client.
3. The server receives the message and validates it. If the message is valid, it will broadcast to all tabs handled by user that `User` has made a message. If it is invalid, it will send back the error message **only to that particular browser tab that sent the message** and not with other tabs even if those tabs have the same `User` logged in.

I already made some parts of it work although I couldn't limit sending the error message to a particular tab, it always broadcast the the error message to all tab sharing the same `User`. Here is my initial code:

```
@MessageMapping("/api/secure/message")
@SendToUser("/api/secure/broadcast")
public HttpEntity createMessage(Message message, Authentication authentication) throws Exception {
    Set<String> errors = TreeSet<String>();
    // Process Message message and add every exceptions encountered to Set errors.
    boolean valid = (errors.size() > 0);
    if(valid) {
        // Broadcast to all.
        return new ResponseEntity(message, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        // Send the message to that particular tab only.
        return new ResponseEntity(errors, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
}
```

Is this achievable through `websocket`? Or should I return back to `XHR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User @Srinivas made a good starting reference point. I have modified the code block in my question with my working code:

```
// inject the [messagingTemplate] bean.
// class org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/api/secure/message")
// Remove the @SendToUser annotation and change return type to void.
// @SendToUser("/api/secure/broadcast")
// public HttpEntity createMessage(Message message…
public void createMessage(Message message, Authentication authentication) throws Exception {
    Set<String> errors = TreeSet<String>();
    // Process Message message and add every exceptions encountered to Set errors.
    boolean valid = (errors.size() > 0);
    if(valid) {
        // Broadcast to all.
        
        // Instead of returning to send the message, use the [messagingTemplate] instead.
        // return new ResponseEntity(message, HttpStatus.OK);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("/api/secure/broadcast", errors);
    }
    else {
        // Send the message to that particular tab only.
        
        // Each STOMP WebSocket connection has a unique ID that effectively differentiate
        // it to the other browser tabs. Retrieve that ID so we can target that specific
        // tab to send our error message with.

        // class org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor
        StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        String sessionId = stompHeaderAccessor.getSessionId();

        // class org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor
        // class org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageType
        // class org.springframework.util.MimeType
        // class java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor simpHeaderAccessor =
            SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
        simpHeaderAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
        simpHeaderAccessor.setContentType(new MimeType("application", "json",
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        simpHeaderAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

        // Instead of returning to send the message, use the [messagingTemplate] instead.
        // It will ensure that it will only broadcast the message to the specific
        // STOMP WebSocket sessionId.
        // return new ResponseEntity(errors, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/api/secure/broadcast",
            errors, simpHeaderAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
    }
}
```

If you are using `@ResponseBody @Valid` on your controller method parameter, you'll have to move the logic lines to your `ControllerAdvice` `exceptionHandler()`.

Answer (score 1):

With every tab you would be creating a new websocket session, hence your stomp session-id would be different as well. So we can decide on whether to send to a particular session or all sessions for a particular user.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;
....
@MessageMapping(...)
public void sendMessage(Message<?> message...) {
 .....
 StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = 
 StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
 String sessionId = headerAccessor.getSessionId();
 ....
 if(valid) {
   //Not specifying session Id so sends all users of 
    <user_name>
   template.cnvertAndSendToUser(<user_name>, 
   <destination>, <payload>)
 }
 else {
  SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = 
  
  SimpMessagingHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
  headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);

  //This will send it to particular session.
  template.convertAndSendToUser(<user_name>, 
                   <destination>, <payload>,  
          headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
  }
}
```

Useful References:

1. [Medium post on sending to particular session.](https://medium.com/@rahul.metangale/sending-message-to-a-specific-session-on-spring-websocket-ccbe4e91fde3)
2. [convertAndSendToUser Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html)

Comment: Where was the variable `watchesSubscription` declared?

Comment: Apologies , I had mistakenly put it there , it should just be the sessionId variable which i got earlier, please check now.